# ifstream read binary file work in release mode but not in debug mode

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm working on a function to read a binary file. I use Visual Studio C++ and it works perfectly in release mode, but not in debug mode. I need to run it in debug to detect potential memory leak.

The function just read an binary file with ifstream and store values. In Debug mode, the program don't read anything. I tried to find a similar problem on the net but nothing (usually, programs work in debug and don't work in release).

```
    string identifier;
    identifier.resize(4);

    ifstream adtFile(m_nameFile, ios::in | ios::binary);

    adtFile.read((char*)&identifier, sizeof(::uint32_t));
```

The file begins with 4 characters, the minimal code above read and store it perfectly in Release Mode, but not in Debug Mode. I suspect the cast to char* is the problem, but I don't understand why.

I don't know all difference between the two configuration, if someone have an idea.

Thanks a lot for reading.

Comment: It's just bad luck that the code "works perfectly" in release mode. A `std::string` object generally holds some data that points at its actual contents. Overwriting that data with a `read` statement doesn't do anything good.

Comment: Most likely _undefined behavior_.

Comment: What is the format of the file that you're reading?

Comment: Most likely, if you fix the debug startup you'll fix one of your leaks as well 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I use Visual Studio C++ and it works perfectly in release mode, but not in debug mode. I need to run it in debug to detect potential memory leak.

it is a bad chance it *seems* to work in release mode, because it cannot works well

> I suspect the cast to char* is the problem

you are right, doing

> ```
> string identifier;
> identifier.resize(4);
>
> ifstream adtFile(m_nameFile, ios::in | ios::binary);
>
> adtFile.read((char*)&identifier, sizeof(::uint32_t));
> ```

you do not write in the internal buffer of 4 characters as you expected but on the *std::string* instance, with an undefined behavior

The minimal change is

```
 string identifier;
 identifier.resize(sizeof(::uint32_t));

 ifstream adtFile(m_nameFile, ios::in | ios::binary);

 adtFile.read((char*)identifier.data(), sizeof(::uint32_t));
```

even to remove the *const* is not clear at all

But is that really what you want ? why to use a `std::string` rather than an  `::uint32_t` like

```
::uint32_t v;

adtFile.read((char*)&v, sizeof(::uint32_t));
```

or just a `std::vector<unsigned char>` / `std::vector<::uint8_t>`

(still with all concerning the byte order)

Is your file contains the external representation of a number (e.g. the characters '1' '2' '3' and '4' for instance) or its internal presentation (e.g. the bytes 0x0 0x0 0x4 0xD2 or 0xD2 0x4 0x0 0x0 depending on the byte order when the file was made).

It can be also interesting to check the possible errors after the read.

Comment: Thanks you ! It works perfectly. This syntax is shared everywhere on the net... Bad luck for me.

I just use string to simplify string comparison further away in the code.

Comment: @AliziaKalineCarina you welcome, happy coding ... and do not trust on the net ... except on some locations like stack overflow of course ^^

Answer (score 0):

You likely want

```
dtFile.read(identifier.data(), 4);
```

or equivalently, `&identifier[0]`